# Open 2 SAP windows in parallel

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, sap-gui

I want to open 2 SAP GUI windows and set up the same transaction, but with different information on it.

I know with VBA/VBS it isn't possible to **run** these windows simultaneously (like other posts I've seen here), but I don't need it to run, I just need the script to set up each window with different information. I can run it manually after the setup.

I've coded the following:

```
Sub YI19Nreport()
Dim app As Object
Dim connection As Object
Dim session As Object
Dim plant As String

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set app = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set connection = app.Children(0)
Set session = connection.Children(0)

Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
Set objSheet = objExcel.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

'''''Opening first YI19N
session.ActiveWindow().findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nyi19n"
session.ActiveWindow().findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_S_WERKS_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
plant = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 4)

session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = plant

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press

'''''Opening second YI19N    
session.ActiveWindow().findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/oyi19n"
session.ActiveWindow().findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/btn%_S_WERKS_%_APP_%-VALU_PUSH").press
plant = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 4)
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/tabsTAB_STRIP/tabpSIVA/ssubSCREEN_HEADER:SAPLALDB:3010/tblSAPLALDBSINGLE/ctxtRSCSEL_255-SLOW_I[1,0]").Text = plant

session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[8]").press
End Sub
```

With this code, the SAP opens the first window, input the information and, instead of opening the second window, completes the first window information with the string I needed for the second one, and after all that it opens the second window and finishes the Sub.

I believe it is related to the "children" info set at the start of the Sub.

If someone can help me, it'll be great.

Comment: Do you know the ID of that "second window"? Which is the string you need for "the second one"? "/oyi19n"?

Comment: @FaneDuru The string "/o..." triggers a new window to open, and the "...yi19n" is the transaction that I use.

Comment: @SandraRossi Sorry, I'm new to SAP/VBA scripting. I didn't understand what you mean by events, is it the coding?

Comment: Did you firstly try “/o”, to create a new session and after that to set  transaction?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes! I tried just opening the session, but it keeps ignoring this command, finishes the edition on the same session, and then it opens the new session (without the transaction).

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with a similar topic in the past. It was about determining whether or not SAP transactions can be executed in parallel using VBA. And if so, what does it save in terms of time compared to serial execution of SAP transactions.

You could only solve it with a workaround. This consisted of starting a VB script from a VBA program.

Check out my examples and try to figure out how you could apply it to your issue.

for example:

```
Sub Parallel_Sessions()
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAP_Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SAP_Application.Children(0)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)
Set wshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

Time_1 = TimeValue(Time)

For mysession = 0 To 5
 Set session = Connection.Children(Int(mysession))
 session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
 session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nreiscn"
 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_BUKRS-LOW").Text = "2000"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_USEPTN").SetFocus
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_USEPTN").Selected = True
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_GRID").Selected = True
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_DSPBUP").Selected = True
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_PARTN-LOW").Text = "1"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_PARTN-HIGH").Text = "1000"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_DSPBUP").SetFocus

 If mysession < 5 Then session.createSession

 waitTill = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03")
 While Now() < waitTill
   DoEvents
 Wend

 If mysession = 5 Then
    session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
 Else
    wshell.Run """c:\tmp\Script_parallel_Sessions.vbs""" & " " & mysession
 End If

Next

Time_2 = TimeValue(Time)
Time_0 = Round((Time_2 - Time_1) * 24 * 3600, 2)

MsgBox "This run for 6 sessions lasted " & Time_0 & " s ", vbInformation + vbMsgBoxForeground, "Note"
End Sub
```

Script_parallel_Sessions.vbs:

```
If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
for mysession  = 0 to 5
    if cstr(mysession) = cstr(wscript.arguments(0)) then
       Set session    = connection.Children(int(mysession))
       session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press
    end if 
next
```

And now serial processing:

```
Sub Seriell_Sessions()
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAP_Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set Connection = SAP_Application.Children(0)
Set session = Connection.Children(0)

Time_1 = TimeValue(Time)
For mysession = 0 To 5
 Set session = Connection.Children(Int(mysession))
 session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
 session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nreiscn"
 session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtS_BUKRS-LOW").Text = "2000"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_USEPTN").SetFocus
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_USEPTN").Selected = True
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_GRID").Selected = True
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_DSPBUP").Selected = True
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_PARTN-LOW").Text = "1"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtSO_PARTN-HIGH").Text = "1000"
 session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/chkP_DSPBUP").SetFocus

 If mysession < 5 Then session.createSession

 waitTill = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03")
 While Now() < waitTill
   DoEvents
 Wend

 session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press

Next
Time_2 = TimeValue(Time)
Time_0 = Round((Time_2 - Time_1) * 24 * 3600, 2)
MsgBox "This run for 6 sessions lasted " & Time_0 & " s ", vbInformation + vbMsgBoxForeground, "Note"
End Sub
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Answer (score 0):

You may define a handler of the event `CreateSession` of the [GuiApplication](https://help.sap.com/viewer/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/760.02/en-US/a4e022f6c155414d9c8ae8eba422cac5.html?q=GuiSession) object.

The following code is a VBScript taken from the link and adapted so that the global object `lastOpenedSession` is initialized with the last opened session:

```
Dim lastOpenedSession ' Global GuiSession object
Dim objSapGui
Set objSapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")

Dim objScriptingEngine
Set objScriptingEngine = objSapGui.GetScriptingEngine
WScript.ConnectObject objScriptingEngine,  "Engine_"

Dim Waiting
Waiting = 1

Do While (Waiting = 1)
 WScript.Sleep(100)
Loop

Set objScriptingEngine = Nothing
Set objSapGui = Nothing

Sub Engine_CreateSession(ByVal Session)
  Dim result
  Set lastOpenedSession = Session
  result = MsgBox("Session created", vbOKCancel)
  If result = vbCancel then
    Waiting = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

The equivalent VBA code is:

- Create a class module `AppHandler`:

```
Private WithEvents app_ As SAPFEWSELib.GuiApplication
Private Sub app_CreateSession(ByVal session As SAPFEWSELib.GuiSession)
  Dim result
  Set lastOpenedSession = Session
  result = MsgBox("Session created", vbOKCancel)
  If result = vbCancel then
    Waiting = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

- Main code:

```
Dim lastOpenedSession ' Global GuiSession object
Dim objSapGui
Set objSapGui = GetObject("SAPGUI")

Dim objScriptingEngine
Set objScriptingEngine = objSapGui.GetScriptingEngine
Set objAppHandler = New AppHandler
Set objAppHandler.app_ = objScriptingEngine

Dim Waiting
Waiting = 1

Do While (Waiting = 1)
 Application.Sleep(100)
Loop

Set objAppHandler = Nothing
Set objScriptingEngine = Nothing
Set objSapGui = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! But I couldn't run this script in my file, do I need to set a different "references"?

Comment: Thank you very much again, I'll take some time to study your answer, there are many functions that I'm not familiarized :)